# Run php-fpm pools with NICE values

Tags: php, nice

Can php-fpm pools have NICE values?
Each one of my pools run under it's own user and group, like:

```
[pool1]
user = pool1
group = pool1
...
```

I've tried to create `/etc/security/limits.d/prio.conf` with contents:

```
@pool1  hard  priority  39
```

But with `htop` that pool still have she same `PRI` and `NI` values than other pools after reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use https://www.php.net/manual/install.fpm.configuration.php#worker-process-priority

```
[pool]
process.priority = 10
```